# WPF Работа с дочерними элементами шаблона

Tags: wpf, шаблоны

Желаемое поведение:

Приложение имеющее несколько кнопок, по нажатию каждой из которой в TabControl создаётся соответствующий Tab из шаблона (хранятся в ресурсах, все шаблоны разные). Предположим, что Tab содержит простую кнопка и TextBox.

При нажатии кнопки происходит следующее:

переменная int (создаваемая в момент создания вкладки) получает +1 к своему значению и отображается в TextBox.

Как видно может быть создано несколько одинаковых Tab, при этом у каждого из них свои переменные, не зависящие друг от друга. Любой  Tab может быть закрыт пользователем.

Я разобрался как создать шаблон, создавать вкладки и закрывать их, но не понимаю:

1. как при генерации вкладки создать набор нужных переменных и
2. как потом к ним обратиться при нажатии кнопки внутри вкладки.
3. Кроме того проблема отыскать TextBox именно той вкладки, в которой была нажата кнопка (решение этой части проблемы описано в справке [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements) - оно рабочее, но мягко говоря хотелось бы попроще - в реальном приложении порядка 30 контроллов на каждой форме, для каждого из них проводить такой громоздкий поиск очень не хочется).

Comment: На помощь придет MVVM!

Comment: Не стесняйтесь  - раскройте свою мысль до конца!